# Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Value'

Tags: haskell

I am writing package manager and I stuck at checking is file installed.

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ../src/beaver.hs, ../src/.o/Main.o)
../src/beaver.hs:57:37:
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Value'
Expected type: [Value]
  Actual type: [[Char]]
In the second argument of `mapM', namely `(splitOn " " files)'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: mapM isFileInstalled (splitOn " " files)
```

Here is code of problematic function(s):

```
installpkg = do
          args <- getArgs
          pkgname <- readProcess "beaver-pkgname" [(args !! 1)] ""
          extractpkg pkgname
          files <- metaprop "files" pkgname
          mapM isFileInstalled (splitOn " " files)
 isFileInstalled f = do
            dbcon <- openConnection "/var/lib/beaver/pkgs.db"
            res <- execParamStatement dbcon "SELECT owner FROM files WHERE path = :path" [(":path", f)] :: IO (Either String [[Row Value]])
            when (null res) (putStrLn "file exists")
            closeConnection dbcon
```

I were searching for solution but I cannot find anything.

Also, is there a way to convert string or text to FilePath?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `execParamStatement` in `isFileInstalled` is:

```
execParamStatement :: SQLiteResult a => SQLiteHandle -> String -> [(String, Value)] -> IO (Either String [[Row a]])
```

that means that `[(":path", f)]` is of type `[(String, Value)]` and `f` is dedecued to be of type `Value`.

This all means that `isFileInstalled` is deduced to take a `Value` as first argument.

Now in the other `installpkg` function you are calling:

```
mapM isFileInstalled (splitOn " " files)
```

and `mapM` is deduced to be from:

```
mapM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
```

to:

```
mapM :: (Value -> IO b) -> [Value] -> IO [b]
```

for whatever `b` is deduced there (it's hard to figure out because you don't put explicit type signatures for functions).

This all means that `mapM` is expected to get a list of `[Value]` from `(splitOn " " files)`, which it's not. `(splitOn " " files)` is returning a `[String]` which is incompatible with `[Value]`.

Since `Value` has a constructor that takes a `String`, you can use:

```
(map Text . splitOn " " $ files)
```

instead of:

```
(splitOn " " files)
```

and make it type check at least.

---

> Also, is there a way to convert string or text to FilePath?

As far as `FilePath` is concerned, that's [just an alias](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.html#FilePath) for `String`, so you don't need to convert to it to use it in the context where it's required a `String`.

---

Finally for the sake of those reading the code and you reasoning about it, **write top level types signatures for functions**, thanks.

Comment: if you are depending on the [system-filepath](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath-0.4.13.4) library FilePath is **not** the same as `String` even though this library is deprecated a few projects still use it.